# Multiple background images in one div, one image after the other

Tags: css, background-image

Lets say that I have 2 images, one is **1px*700px** and the second is **1px*800px**. I want to put those images as a `background` to one `div`, so that the `div` has **1500px** height.

Is that possible with CSS3?

```
div{
    background: url(first_image.jpg) repeat-x, url(second_image.jpg) repeat-x;
    /* ... */
}
```

I could "join" those images in Photoshop, but I'm wondering if there is a CSS3 solution.

My problem: currently I have two `divs` and each has one `background-image` so when put together it looks good. My problem is that I have an element that needs to be right in the place where those two `divs` "join", and when I place that element there - it breaks the layout. I could play with `position: absolute`, but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: [Like this example?](http://jsbin.com/fusuve/1/edit?html,css,output) The second background image is red and moved underneath with `bottom`

Comment: @misterManSam well, now I feel stupid ^^ Yes, just like that! Post as the answer.

Comment: No worries ;) I changed your CSS in the question to the `background` shorthand because you have the repeat value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the height of the div equal to the height of both background images, you can use `bottom` to move the second background image underneath the first.

### Example

```css
div {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/5X100) repeat-x, 
  url(http://www.placehold.it/5X100/FF0000) bottom repeat-x;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```